# There is no ImageTarget in Assets/Vuforia/Prefabs

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I followed the instructions to use Vuforia. But when I add ImageTarget, I found there is no ImageTarget in my Assets/Vuforia/Prefabs

The version of my unity is 2018.2.18f1.

I want to create an ImageTarget and Put the resources such as the model we need to display under ImageTarget as its child exists.

[image]

The picture here is what I got in Assets/Vuforia/Prefabs.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/vuforia_get_started_adding_image_targets.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the prefab.

See [Unity Manual: Adding Image Targets to your Scene](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/vuforia_get_started_adding_image_targets.html)

You can simply generate a new ImageTarget by clicking on `GameObject` → `Vuforia` → `Image`

[image]

This should add all required components like `ImageTargetBehaviour`, `DefaultTrackableEventHandler`, `TurnOffBehaviour`, `MeshFilter` and `MeshRenderer`.

---

You can also create it yourself from scratch by simply putting all the required components on an empty `GameObject`.

---

And then go on with configuring your database and target.

[image]